# Frame-rate independent pushForce?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I'm working with a CharacterController and added the ability to push Rigidbodies. The problem is however that the pushing is frame-rate dependent. How would I be able to make it frame-rate independent? I have tried adding Time.deltatime, but this makes pushing not possible, I might be adding it wrong though.

Here's the code that adds force to rigidbodies;

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;

    if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
        return;

    if (hit.moveDirection.y < -.3f)
        return;

    Vector3 pushDirection = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);
    body.velocity = pushForce * pushDirection;
}
```

As far as I know it has something to do with the last 2 lines of code.

Edit(The code for pushing):

```
public void PushStates() {
    // Creating the raycast origin Vector3's
    Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * distanceForPush;
    Vector3 middle = controller.transform.position - new Vector3(0, -controller.height / 2, 0);

    // Inspector bool
    if (pushRay)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(middle, forward, Color.cyan);
    }

    // Force the pushForce and movementSpeed to normal when the player is not pushing
    pushForce = 0f;
    movementSpeed = walkSpeed;

    // Draws a raycast in front of the player to check if the object in front of the player is a pushable object
    if (Physics.Raycast(middle, forward, out hit, distanceForPush))
    {
        if (InputManager.BButton() && playerIsInPushingTrigger)
        {
            PushableInfo();

            playerIsPushing = true;
            anim.SetBool("isPushing", true);

            if (hit.collider.tag == "PushableLight")
            {
                pushForce = playerPushForceLight;
                movementSpeed = pushSpeedLight;
            }
            else if (hit.collider.tag == "PushableHeavy")
            {
                pushForce = playerPushForceHeavy;
                movementSpeed = pushSpeedHeavy;
            }

            // Checks the players speed now instead off movement. This is neccesary when the player is pushing a pushable into a collider. 
            // The player and pushable never stop moving because of force.
            if (currentSpeed < 0.15f)
            {
                //Removes all remaining velocity, when the player stops pushing
                pushableObjectRB.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                pushableObjectRB.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

                anim.SetFloat("pushSpeedAnim", 0f);
            }
            else
            {
                // Calls a rotation method
                PushingRot();
                if (hit.collider.tag == "PushableLight")
                {
                    anim.SetFloat("pushSpeedAnim", pushSpeedAnimLight);
                }
                else if (hit.collider.tag == "PushableHeavy")
                {
                    anim.SetFloat("pushSpeedAnim", pushSpeedAnimHeavy);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isPushing", false);
            pushForce = 0f;
            movementSpeed = walkSpeed;
            playerIsPushing = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isPushing", false);
        playerIsPushing = false;
    }

    // Setting the time it takes to rotate when pushing
    AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    if (stateInfo.fullPathHash == pushStateHash)
    {
        turnSmoothTime = maxTurnSmoothTimePushing;
    }
    else
    {
        turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, you need to multiply by Time.deltaTime which is the time elapsed since last rendered frame.
As this number is really small (has you have 60+ fps) you'll also need to increase the value (multiply it by 100, 1000...)

Comment: You mean I need to increase the pushForce? And how abouts do I go multiplying by Time.deltaTime if I may ask?

Comment: Just do `body.velocity = pushForce * pushDirection * Time.deltaTime * someValueToAdjust`
However, you're not doing it in an Update, loop or anything so it should not be framerate dependent in the first place ?

Comment: What is the someValueToAdjust? And indeed this is not directly within the update function, but when the CharacterController collides with a rigidbody, doesn't this mean it automatically is run in Update?

Comment: Ah I think the value to adjust is i.e. * 100 right? I have only tested this for seconds, but it seems to work. However after disabling v-sync it still seems to be frame-rate dependent for some reason?

Comment: Yes, use someValue to get the desired effect. But again, if you don't do this in a loop, or in update, it should not be framerate dependent. If it is I don't know why, sorry :x

Comment: I do have to say the rest of the pushing mechanics is done via update. I have updated the question with the added code. Maybe that will make a bit of sense?

Comment: `multiply it by 100, 1000...)` wouldn't more or less `60` be enough? ;)

Comment: Hi, yeah I'm multiplying by 50 atm and that seems about good, do you have any idea why the pushing maintains frame-rate dependent?